# dalvikvm: Could not find class followed by crash

Tags: android, crash, dalvik

I am facing a strange problem for which I dont find any help on the net. 
When I execute the app, I see in the console:

> E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.example.xxx.ganew.OurUser',
>   referenced from method
>   com.example.xxx.ganew.util.PreferenceUtils.getUserAccount

This message is shown when the constructor (!) of PreferenceUtils is called. The method getUserAccount is not called then.

This message is then repeated for other classes that I instantiate after this one.

The crash occurs on one of the classes I instantiate. Exception is: java.lang.VerifyError

The app compiles fine and all classes, including 'OurUser' exist. 
App has been working without problem, and literally out of the blue, I get these error messages followed by a crash.

I have tried with Api 19 , 21 and 22.
I have cleaned project. I have rebooted device and Mac.
I have even recreated the project from scratch, but it doesnt help.

The code where it happens:

```
ForAll.preferences = new PreferenceUtils(this);
```

...

```
public PreferenceUtils(Context paramContext) {
    this.context = paramContext;
    this.mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(paramContext);
}
```

Comment: You need to find more logs. Disable the filter and search with tag dalvikvm. And paste it here if you find something.